# R - subsetting rows from a data frame for column values within a vector

Tags: r

Have a data.frame, df as below

```
id | name | value
1  | team1 | 3
1  | team2 | 1
2  | team1 | 1
2  | team2 | 4
3  | team1 | 0
3  | team2 | 6 
4  | team1 | 1
4  | team2 | 2 
5  | team1 | 3
5  | team2 | 0
```

How do we subset the data frame to get rows for all values of id from 2:4 ?

We can apply conditionally like `df[,df$id >= 2 & df$id <= 4]` . But is there a way to directly use a vector of integer ranges like `ids <- c(2:4)` to subset a dataframe ?

One way to do this is `df[,df$id >= min(ids) & df$id <= max(ids)]`.

Is there a more elegant R way of doing this ?

Comment: `df[df$id %in% ids,]`. Or `subset(df,subset=id %in% ids)`

Answer (score 2):

The most typical way is mentioned already, but also variations using `match`

```
with(df, df[match(id, 2:4, F) > 0, ])
```

or, similar

```
with(df, df[is.element(id, 2:4), ])
```

Comment: Or `library(data.table);setDT(df, key='id')[.(2:4)]`

Comment: are you using the devel version?  Otherwise you may need `setkey(setDT, id)[.(2:4)]`